# Jenkins linter: did not contain the 'pipeline' step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When checking a working Jenkins script with the [pipeline linter](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/development/) I get the following feedback:
`Jenkinsfile content 'node('xxx') ... did not contain the 'pipeline' step.`

A shortened example giving the same error:

```
node('xxx'){
  try  {
    stage("Get jenkins utils")    {
      echo 'get utils to support my builds'
    }
  }
  catch (Exception err)  {
    echo err.getMessage()
  }
}
```

How do I add pipeline step to resolve this feedback without affecting the current working of the pipeline scripts. Ideally I want Jenkins to check it as a scripted pipeline.

I am not sure what the intent of the pipeline step would be and where to add it. It feels like the try catch must be replaced with a different mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

This will work returning `Jenkinsfile successfully validated.`:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label 'xxx'
  }
  stages {
    stage("Get jenkins utils") {
      steps {
        error 'fubar'
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    always {
      echo "done"
    }
    failure {
      echo "failure"
    }
  }
}
```

I was using scripted pipelines and [linter can only handle declarative pipelines](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/development/). The above should be the declarative equivalent to my scripted example in the question.

Right now I am not sure this is the best way to use it, I need to experiment more.